# How to update an object in a more pythonic way

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently, I am Updating a shopping list item as below

```
def update_item(self, name, price, quantity, shoppinglist):
        # updates self If the variable is not equal to the name None
        if name != "None":
            self.name = name
        if price != "None":
            self.price = price
        if quantity != "None":
            self.quantity = quantity
        if shoppinglist != "None":
            self.shoppinglist_id = shoppinglist.id
        db.session.commit()
```

I, however, feel there could be a better way to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you're trying to update everything at once, and using a "None" string as a indicator value are complicating things. Why not just have a separate setter for each? Or pass in a dictionary?

Comment: It's a Flask API and am using string "None" just to signify that the user does not want to update that field. If I use setters for each should they all still check if the value equals "None"??

Comment: This feels bad. You should set every variable, even if that variable is set to "None". That way, when you try and access a variable, it won't crash.

Comment: @ddg Since its an update method the app won't crash since it will retain its previous values if the value is not updated

Comment: oh I’m sorry, didn’t realize

Comment: Any Suggestion on how I could improve this???

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. It has the same behavior as your example function, while being more concise.

```
def update_items(self, **kwargs):
    assert set(kwargs) == {"name", "price", "quantity", "shoppinglist"}

    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if val!="None": 
            setattr(self, key, val)

    db.session.commit()
```

If you want optional parameters with default values, then you should do this.

```
def update_item(self, name=None, price=None, quantity=None, shoppinglist=None):
    # updates self If the variable is not equal to the name None
    if name is not None:
        self.name = name
    if price is not None:
        self.price = price
    if quantity is not None:
        self.quantity = quantity
    if shoppinglist is not None:
        self.shoppinglist_id = shoppinglist.id
    db.session.commit()
```

You can combine both these approaches:

```
def update_items(self, **kwargs):
    okay = {"name", "price", "quantity", "shoppinglist"}

    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if val in okay and val!="None": 
            setattr(self, key, val)

    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know beforehand what values the user wants to update. i.e he/she may want to update the price while another may want to update the name